# Historical memory usage, clarification needed

Tags: redhat, process, memory-usage

I am running on Red Hat Linux 6.6

I have a process that is started daily, whose name and PID I know.

```
user 13697 13583  0 02:15 ?        00:00:21 /a/b/my_process
```

How can I find out:

1. How much memory does this process consume?
2. How much memory does this process consume on average in a given week?

Assume there is no memory leak. We're doing this to load balance applications.

Comment: I would use a script [like this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py) in cron to record the data.  I would probably send the output to syslog so I can get the data in one place.  There are other ways using process accounting but I have always found the output harder to parse and that is a bit heavier handed.  The python script is self contained and targetted to your one need.